# Executing PowerShell from a Window command batch script using the Start-Process command with named parameters

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am attempting to execute a Powershell Start-Process command with a named parameter list from a Windows command script.  I tried including the named parameters;(-productname, -platform, -version, -exepath, -exe, -installMode) in the ArgumentList, however, they when the PowerShell process starts it appears to fail to see them.  The command I am using is below:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""setadminstartandcreateshortcut.ps1"" -productname %PRODUCTNAME%  -platform %PLATFORM% -version %VERSION% -exepath %TARGET% -exe %PRODUCTNAME%.exe -installMode %INSTALLMODE%' -Verb RunAs}"
```